# Using workflows in Dynamics CRM. Static fields?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

My first question here. I am relatively new to Dynamics CRM and I am looking to do a customization using workflows and I have run into some issues.

I need to trigger an email to a user if I have 5 records with a specific value chosen in an option set within the last 15 days.I thought I might need a static variable kind of field for the entity. I don't really know how to get that in CRM.

While I have been able to use workflows to get the records within the 2 dates and increment the count for that condition, the count maintained is not static and so it is basically useless for my requirements.

Any suggestions to work around this?

Comment: Bit more info needed here. What do you mean by a static field in the CRM context? And what are the the requirements around that field? Sounds like you just need to trigger a workflow?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. When I referred to static, I mentioned it in the programming sense. I want to save a certain count of records based on a specific field. 
Eg. I have 100 contacts... Say 50 of them are male and over the age of 60. I want to get this value(50) and trigger a workflow based on that. Now this value would be constant for all records at one point of time. How do I go about setting such a value and using it with a workflow?

Comment: I would recomend you to read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531067.aspx) because this is a basic use of workflows. If you need to query data you may need a [custom workflows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309745.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is to have a custom workflow.

Whenever a new record for that entity is created, run this custom workflow and get the count and return it via an Output parameter. Check for the output value and if that is more than the threshold as in the requirement, then consider the step for sending an email to the user, otherwise complete the workflow as succeeded.